# How to get low battery level threshold value on windows UWP app?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, batterylevel

In Windows power options you can set a specific threshold (%) when OS notifies when if battery is in low/critical level. My question is there away to get this value on my C# UWP application? I cant find an API that provides this functionality to get the value or event from OS.

I would like to know is possible to get the threshold values from OS instead of hard coding values like 0.1 for low and 0.07 for critical. I mean the threshold percentage values in advanced power settings, that user can define.

Comment: Maybe this helps you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/get-battery-info

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct API to do it but you can create one.

Here is a sample code

```
public Page()
{
    ....
    Battery.AggregateBattery.ReportUpdated += AggregateBattery_ReportUpdated;

}

private void AggregateBattery_ReportUpdated(Battery sender, object args)
{
    var batteryReport = Battery.AggregateBattery.GetReport();

    var percentage = (batteryReport.RemainingCapacityInMilliwattHours.Value / (double)batteryReport.FullChargeCapacityInMilliwattHours.Value);

    if ((percentage == 0.1 || percentage == 0.07) && batteryReport.Status == Windows.System.Power.BatteryStatus.Discharging)
    {
        // Your Code
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have done exactly what you shown above, but I would like to know is possible to get the threshold values from OS instead of hard coding 0.1 and 0.07.

I mean the threshold percentage values in advanced power settings, that user can define.

Comment: @Mako I don't think it's possible. Also, add this info in your question

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer and feedback. I re-edited the question